# CFn: Use !If to add multiple Principals to a statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have the following template defining a IAM policy which is not working:

```
      RoleName: 'ABCRole'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
              - 1234567890 # Some AWS account
              - !If
                - !And
                  - !Condition Condition1
                  - !Condition Condition2
                - arn:aws:iam::11111111111111:role/ABCDE_Role # first role
                - arn:aws:iam::22222222222222:role/ABCDE_Role # second role (different account number)
                - !Ref AWS:NoValue
```

I am trying to achieve that: when both `Condition1` and `Condition2` are true, I will be able to attach `arn:aws:iam::11111111111111:role/ABCDE_Role` and `arn:aws:iam::22222222222222:role/ABCDE_Role` as two additional principals. Otherwise, do nothing -- having `1234567890` as the only principal.

Please note that, `arn:aws:iam::11111111111111:role/ABCDE_Role` and `arn:aws:iam::22222222222222:role/ABCDE_Role` are only different from the aws account, so maybe I could use `!Sub` to replace the the account number? Somewhat like:

```
for account in [11111111111111, 22222222222222]:
 !Sub arn:aws:iam::${account}:role/ABCDE_Role
```

How should I modify my template above? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with your current template? Any errors?

Comment: `!If` was complaining about the format. I just learned the fact that the first parameter of `!If` must be a `Condition` so maybe using a nested `!And` is wrong.

Comment: That's one, but there is much more wrong with it. Can you post the actual error msg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think is because of the format that the **!If** condition expects, following the documentation from [aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if), the format is:

```yaml
!If [condition_name, value_if_true, value_if_false]
```

And if you check your template, you have four elements, not three.

Also, the pseudo parameter is (with double :):

```yaml
AWS::NoValue
```

So, a possible solution to add the two accounts that you need when the condition is True could be trying to add a new condition that combines condition1 and condition2 that you already have with the !And function, like this:

```yaml
Conditions:
  Condition1: your condition
  Condition2: your condition
  ConditionCombined: !And [!Condition Condition1, !Condition Condition2]
Resources:
  Role1:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties: 
      RoleName: 'ABCRole'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
              - 1234567890 # Some AWS account
              - !If
                - ConditionCombined
                - arn:aws:iam::11111111111111:role/ABCDE_Role # first role
                - !Ref AWS::NoValue
              - !If
                - ConditionCombined
                - arn:aws:iam::22222222222222:role/ABCDE_Role # second role (different account number)
                - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```